# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'buy'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting an error ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Buy') but I can't get rid of this error even though I've checked everything

```
import pandas as pd
import ta
import numpy as np
import time
from binance import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def getminutedata(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback+' min ago UTC'))
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:6]
    frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    frame = frame.set_index('Time')
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    return frame

df = getminutedata('ADAUSDT', '1m', '100')

def applytechnicals(df):
    df['%K'] = ta.momentum.stoch(df.High,df.Low,df.Close, window=14,
                                 smooth_window=3)
    df['%D'] = df['%K'].rolling(3).mean()
    df['rsi'] = ta.momentum.rsi(df.Close, window=14)
    df['macd'] = ta.trend.macd_diff(df.Close)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

applytechnicals(df)

class Signals:
    
    def __init__(self,df, lags):
        self.df = df
        self.lags = lags
        
    def gettrigger(self):
        dfx = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(self.lags + 1):
            mask = (self.df['%K'].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df['%D'].shift(i) < 20)
            dfx = dfx.append(mask, ignore_index=True)
        return dfx.sum(axis=0)
    
    def decide(self):
        self.df['trigger'] = np.where(self.gettrigger(), 1, 0)
        self.df['Buy'] = np.where((self.df.trigger) & 
    (self.df['%K'].between(20,80)) & (self.df['%D'].between(20,80)) 
                                  & (self.df.rsi >  50) & (self.df.macd > 0), 1, 0)

inst = Signals(df, 100)

inst.decide()

inst.decide()

strategy('ADAUSDT', 4)
```

When I run the code "strategy('ADAUSDT', 4)" I get the output "current Close is x.xx" and then the error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Buy'"

[image: photo of the error]

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the code that gives the error. But from the error message, the 'buy' column should be inside the iloc, not outside

Explain better what you are trying to do with the iloc

Comment: the error code is shown in the photo "if df.Buy.iloc[-1]:", I'm checking to meet the conditions